# Does Gradle print text like CMake?

Tags: java, gradle, cmake

I have a question about Gradle tasks. I'm following the tutorial about tasks, and I have this code: `task('hello') << { println "tutorialspoint" }`

Is the `println` method a way to print text like this, like the one that is in CMake when compiling software?

> make[2]: Entering directory '/home/kristi/Downloads/pidgin-2.13.0/share/ca-certs'
>
> While adding external dependencies. Gradle looks for them in a repository. A repository is just a collection of files, organized by group, name, and version. By default, Gradle does not define any repositories. We have to define at least one repository explicitly. The following code snippet defines how to define a maven repository. Use this code in build. Gradle file.

I also couldn't understand repository.

Comment: The `println` method prints to the standard output. And what don't you understand about "repository"? As it says, it's a collection of files organized in a specific way. They can be remote or local. When you add a dependency Gradle will search the repository (or repositories) for the first matching item. If the repository is remote then Gradle will download the dependency automatically.

Comment: 1. Search for a more up-to-date tutorial. Your example code uses the deprecated task operator `<<`.
2. The method `println` is actually provided by a static import of `System.out` known from Java.
3. You should be more specific about what you do not understand about repositories.